# Rails migration file can't access models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Enrollment` model with a `status` column that is populated by a (poorly formed) seed file. Currently, all of these `status` values are found in the `EnrollmentState` column `stateId` (which contains negative values and is not meant to be the typical index column of a table). Here are the relevant schema tables:

`db/schema.rb`

```
  create_table "enrollment_states", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "stateId", limit: 1,  default: 0,     null: false
    t.string  "Name",    limit: 20
    t.boolean "Display", limit: 1,  default: false
  end

  create_table "enrollments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "status",               limit: 1, default: 0
    t.integer  "project_id",           limit: 2, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "subjId",               limit: 4,             null: false
    t.integer  "homeId",               limit: 4,             null: false
    t.datetime "startDate"
    t.integer  "RAId",                 limit: 4, default: 0
    t.integer  "eligibility_state_id", limit: 1, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "secondary",            limit: 1, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "idx",                  limit: 4, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "enrollment_state_id",  limit: 4
  end
```

I have created the `enrollment_state_id` column in the `Enrollment` model to create an association and was hoping to populate it with the `Enrollment_State` id that corresponds to the `status` column.

I have tried to do this with the following migration:

```
  class UpdateColumnValues < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      Enrollment.connection.schema_cache.clear!
      Enrollment.reset_column_information

      Enrollment.all.each do |e|
        e.update_attribute(enrollment_state_id: EnrollmentState.find_by(stateId: e.status).id)
      end
    end
  end
```

However, the migration file cannot find the `Enrollment` data in the database! I get this error in my console after running `rake db:migrate`:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'enrollment.enrollment' doesn't exist: SELECT `enrollment`.* FROM `enrollment`/Users/ben/Desktop/enrollment_app/db/migrate/20150711175101_update_column_values.rb:6:in `change'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'enrollment.enrollment' doesn't exist: SELECT `enrollment`.* FROM `enrollment`
/Users/ben/Desktop/enrollment_app/db/migrate/20150711175101_update_column_values.rb:6:in `change'
Mysql2::Error: Table 'enrollment.enrollment' doesn't exist
/Users/ben/Desktop/enrollment_app/db/migrate/20150711175101_update_column_values.rb:6:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas why my migration file can't access my `Enrollment` or `EnrollmentState` models? Or how to do this another way maybe?

Comment: Don't use uppercase in names for your database columns - anything starting with an uppercase letter is supposed to be a constant in Ruby and a Rails model with attributes like `Foo.BAR` or `Foo.Bar` is really confusing. Use snake case instead.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have done something foolish like `table_name 'enrollment'` in your `app/models/enrollment.rb`? Rails can find the model fine - but the sql query is using the wrong table name. Thats the most likely  cause unless you have messed up the [inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) for the word `enrollment` which is is pretty unlikely.

Comment: @max, I did do something foolish like that actually. I have self.table_name = 'enrollment' in my `app/models/enrollment.rb`. I don't remember what for, maybe for my search function that I have implemented as well. I can't say I understand why this is so bad, but I will try changing it and seeing what happens.

Comment: Also, I agree about the table column names, but they are all from the bad seedfile I mentioned earlier.

Comment: What do you mean from the seed file? The `db/seeds.rb` is used to add records to the database - not to define database columns. Is this an application you have inherited from someone else or have you created it?

Comment: In your rails console, what is the result of Enrollment.table_name ?

Comment: Well my `db/seeds.rb` has a call to read in a `.sql` file that I didn't write.

Comment: But thank you so much @max, when I removed the `self.table_name = "enrollment"` from my `enrollment.rb`, the migration worked! Great first experience here on StackOverflow. I don't think I would have ever gotten that otherwise and had already wasted hours on it. If I could upvote you I would.

Comment: @DanDraper, the answer to your question is "enrollments". I didn't know you could do that, thanks. I'm sure I will run into problems with that again so it will be helpful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails can find the model fine but it is looking in the wrong table for your enrollments. As you already have discovered this is due setting the `table_name` of your `Enrollment` model.

Rails is built around strong conventions, follow them and everything tends to go pretty smoothly. Break them and you end up like a drag queen in a nazi convention.

The ActiveRecord convention is that models have a singular name (`User`) which corresponds to a table in the plural `users`. Columns which end with `_id` are foreign keys.

Since Rails is so strongly built on convention than the first step if you have to use an existing database structure from somewhere else should be writing migrations to beat the database into conformity. Rename columns to `snake_case`. Make sure any columns that reference other tables have indexes and foreign keys. This avoid stupid time consuming errors because you have done ’status_id’ (which is correct) instead of `statusId`.

And you will be able to pass your work to other developers without feeling ashamed.

Comment: And get the heck rid of that SQL file from your seeds file. Just use seeds to create records that need to be in the database for your application to work. 

Never have anything which does ALTER or CREATE TABLE statements in your app except in your migrations.

Comment: Thank you so much, part of my assignment was to fix the sql file problems, which I already have done a lot of but will continue to do so based on the Rails conventions you mentioned. Lots more migrations to come. Thanks again!